# Differentiate between superuser and registered user in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, root

how can we differentiate between superuser and registered user in joomla 2.5? in joomla 1.5 there was option of user type but in 2.5 there in no option .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would be best off doing it this way:

1. First find out the groups the user is a member of
2. Then check those groups against for 'core.admin' privileges against the Root Asset (root asset is id=1 in #__assets)

e.g.

```
$groups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser($UserId)
if(JAccess::getAssetRules(1)->allow('core.admin', $groups))
{
    // we have root
}
```